# How to golf wrap-around assignments?

Tags: code-golf, tips, javascript

This is a relatively simple question. I'm trying to golf a Snake game I've written, and I'm trying to work out if there's a way to golf the following conditional assignments which control x and y coordinates of the snake ensuring a wrap around of the play area:

```
if (P<0) {
  P = T-1;
}
if (P>T-1) {
  P = 0;
}
if (Q<0) {
  Q = T-1;
}
if (Q>T-1) {
  Q = 0;
}
```

Is there a simpler way of expressing these, regardless of the value of T?

Comment: can the values of `Q` and `P` initially be lower than `-1` or larger than `T`?

Comment: @ovs: No, P and Q are such that 0<=P<=T and 0<=Q<=T initially.

Comment: Would [this](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/M01BI8DWVtdQU6GaS0EhQMFWIUTX0JqrlgsqE4KQMIAJByI0BKJqCIRrCIRq@P8fAA) work for your purpose? This handles values `<=-2` and `>T` differently

Comment: Suppose your play area is 10×10, then rather than using `1` and `-1` as your movement amounts, use `1` and `9`, so you can write `x=(x+d)%10`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following, it ensures `x` to be inside `[0, n]` (say `n = 5`), only when `x > -n` and `x < 2n`.

```javascript
x = (5 + x) % 5
```

Thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/V@WmKNgqxCta6SjoGuoo2CgowBkGesomOoomOsoWMT@T87PKy5RSKsAqgJiOwUNUwVthQpNBVUFUy6IZiCpl5tYoJFWoQlWnZ@TqpeTn64BFNf8DwA)

---

As mentioned by [xash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95594/xash) in the comments, if you want to make it work for any `x`, then do

```javascript
x = ((x % 5) + 5) % 5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzNCoMwHMPve4pcBi37V9RN3GV7keGh@DE2Oisq0rfvUj3kRxJIvnazSzt/ptWMvuvjZh0eeJnyJjBFTtRUmYKAke4qqASs74IiKW9i68dlxRC4pZ5QKuCMSuOSQHc6jsnsZyc1BL1vvOsz59@KvY5/)

Comment: You can always add `5` to `x`, if x is non-negative this doesn't change the result.

Comment: that was quick.

Comment: To make it work with any `x`: `((x % 5) + 5) % 5` is the usual mod.

Comment: `[P,Q]=[(P+T)%T,(Q+T)%T]` is the final result based on your answer, and to be honest, that's all I need, I'm not going beyond -1 and x+1, so what you've provided initially is fine... Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, it was suitable for your case @WallyWest, but the generalization by xash was cool!